# How to get events like Undo, Redo and Apply from Aviary SDK in Android

Tags: android, photo, undo-redo, aviary, adobecreativesdk

I have implemented Aviary Photo Editor in my Android app.
I need to get the Undo/Redo and Apply events from Aviary in my App.

Please help me out.
Suggestions really gonna appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

## Paradigm for interacting with the Image Editor

The Creative SDK Image Editor (formerly Aviary) doesn't emit events for redo/undo, but the UI does allow the user to undo and redo.

The paradigm for programmatic interaction with the Image Editor is that you:

1. Configure the Image Editor
2. Launch the Image Editor and pass in an image
3. Receive the resulting edited image

While an image is being edited, no events are emitted to the rest of the program.

## Receiving an edited image

You receive the edited image in the Activity's `onActivityResult()` method.

Here is a basic example:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {

            /* Make a case for the request code we passed to startActivityForResult() */
            case 1: // Can be any int

                /* Show the image! */
                Uri editedImageUri = data.getData();
                mEditedImageView.setImageURI(editedImageUri);

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

## More info

You can get [a sample app to fork and clone on the Creative SDK GitHub account](https://github.com/CreativeSDK/android-getting-started-samples/tree/master/image-editor-ui).

Further information and documentation can be found in [the Creative SDK Image Editor developer guide](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/android/#/articles/imageediting/index.html).